# Microservices database migration with existing foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, microservices

We have a rails application where we need to run a database migration (to add transactional reference data) which refers to a primary key on another independent service. The only way I can think of doing this as of now is adding a http call in the migration to get the key from the other service. Was wondering if there was a cleaner way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just have to get a console and do the work. What's the philosophical point of a migration? To change the database in a replicable/repeatable way, i.e., if you were to re-provision the app or instigate a new development environment. In this case? I'd say screw it, just run a task on production outside a migration.

Maybe, have it make background jobs, so if one fails due to the external service being down, your whole task doesn't restart.

Comment: Adding rake task makes sense. But again as you pointed out this will end up being a manually task every time we have to set up/recreate databases on the development environment ( especially if we insert reference data as a part of migrations which we do in our case ).

Comment: Well, you don't want it automated as part of the migration since you'll mostly be loading from schema instead of migrating step-by-step due to code changes over time. I'd put this in a task, but also in your db:seed file.